# Android emulator access local network - Is it possible to map 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 without changing code?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In the code, I have some places where the string 127.0.0.1. Is there a way for me to tell Android Emulator that all calls to 127.0.0.1 should be like calls to 10.0.2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to replace the String for the correct environment. You can add the piece below to your `android` tag inside the app `build.gradle` file.

```
flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {
    device {
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_WEB_URL", "127.0.0.1"
    }
    emulator {
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_WEB_URL", "10.0.2.2"
    }
}

//comment this block if you want the emulatorRelease build variant (but you probably wont)
variantFilter { variant ->
    def names = variant.flavors*.name
    if (variant.buildType.name == "release" && names.contains("emulator")) {
        // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
        setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

In this way you will have 3 build variants (you can change build variant on the left  bottom panel of Android Studio). Based on the build variant you choose, you will have the `BASE_WEB_URL` correctly updating to the right value.

In your code you simply need to replace all your "127.0.0.1" and "10.0.2.2" with

```
BuildConfig.BASE_WEB_URL
```